# Update whole table in one query

Tags: php, mysql

If there's duplicated topic - please, forgive me, but i haven't found a solution yet. First of all, I've got one php file (update.php). This file contains:

```
<form action='update.php' method='post'>
<table border='1'>
    <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "exchange";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        $sql = "SELECT ID, name, symbol, buy, sell FROM exchangevalues";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' name='ID' value='".$row["ID"]."'>";
                echo "<td>".$row["name"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>Buy: <input type='text' name='buy' value='".$row['buy']."'></td>";
                echo "<td>Sell: <input type='text' name='sell' value='".$row['sell']."'></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
<table>
```

There's 14 rows and 5 columns in my db. How do i update every row in columns 'buy' and 'sell' on 'click' (isset submit button) with new values? I've tried with ID[], buy[], but I've got problems with loop and i cannot handle it. I'm running MySQL on localhost, also i know that only last row will be updated without running loop, but still...

Comment: What have you tried? If you submit each row as an array (ID[], buy[], sell[]), you should be able to run as many update queries as the server received array items

Comment: *"How do i update every row in columns 'buy' and 'sell' on 'click' (isset submit button) with new values?"* - UPDATE maybe? where's that bit of code?

Comment: *"I've tried with ID[], buy[]"* - That's how I'd do it.  *"but I've got problems with loop and i cannot handle it"* - And what were those problems?  Nobody here can tell you what's wrong with an attempt you haven't shown or in any way described.  "I tried something but I gave up and want someone to do it for me" isn't a valid Stack Overflow question.

Comment: If you have a unique key on each row, then just `UPDATE ... WHERE <uniqueue_key=X>` in your loop. If not, I am not sure that I understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have corresponding php code to process the input, here is a sample of what you'll need to do for the HTML when creating the form:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $i=0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='ID[" . $i . "]' value='".$row["ID"]."'>";
        echo "<td>".$row["name"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
```

On the php side to process the input, you can do something like this:

```
$id_array = $_REQUEST["ID"];
foreach($id_array as $id){
    //do insert with $id 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what i was looking for!